# Not able to get nJupiter.DataAccess.Ldap work with our Internal LDAP (Lotus Domino)

Tags: asp.net, ldap, lotus-domino, membership-provider

I've tried everything possible, to setup nJupiter.DataAccess.Ldap as the membership provider on our intranet based web application built using asp.net 3.5.

Challenges I am facing:

1. Not able to authenticate the user using the default login webpart (says Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again)
2. I tried this code and I receive a COMException : "There is no such object on the server."

   var ldapMembershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser("username") as LdapMembershipUser;

   if (ldapMembershipUser != null)
   {
       var givenName = ldapMembershipUser.Attributes["givenName"];
   }

I have placed my web.config and the nJupiter.DataAccess.Ldap.config here:

web.config : http://pastebin.com/9XdDnhUH

nJupiter.DataAccess.Ldap.config : http://pastebin.com/WsSEhi98

I have tried all possible permutations and combinations for different values in the XML and i am not able to take it forward. Please guide. I just am not able to connec to the LDAP and authenticate the user or even search for users.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your config is unlikely to be enough since I don't know your Domino server's confguration, so my answer isn't an attempt to fix your problem. It's an attempt to teach you how I would approach it if it were my problem. Here's what I do to troubleshoot connections and queries from code to Domino LDAP:

- Configure the Domino LDAP server for logging the highest level of debug information with the notes.ini setting LDAPDEBUG=7. See this [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21203191) for more info.
- Use an LDAP client and figure out how to successfully connect to the Domino LDAP server. I like the free Softerra client for this. Check the logs and save off the info from your successful connection.
- Now run your code and compare what you see in the logs against the successful connection.
- If the code is making it past authentication but failing on the query, then find the actual query in the log, go back to your LDAP client, figure out what the query should have been, and adjust your code's configuration appropriately.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I do not have access to our corporate ldap, i have raised a request to the IT but i dont think they would bother making any changes.
I am already using teh softerra's free ldap client, and it seems to connect just fine and i am able to query the directory with anonymous authentication. the same thing just doesnt work when using nJupiter. I have tried various combinations in the xml and max i could get from the server was the username and password is incorrect, which is not helpful because i am using the right credentials to access the ldap.